# $(ProjectDir) doesn't resolve to actual project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio for writing in c++.
I try to use $(ProjectDir) macro to access the project directory

```
auto vertShaderCode = readFile("$(ProjectDir)shaders/vert.spv");
```

And unfortunately the macro doesn't resolve to actual path, but rather stays exactly as "$(ProjectDir).

ChatGPT suggested writing like this:

```
std::string projectPath = "$(SolutiontDir)";
auto vertShaderCode = readFile(projectPath + "shaders/vert.spv");
```

But it doesn't work as well.
I have specifically added this macro in "Additional Include Directories" in project properties, but it still stays the same.

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. For later problem about RAW string , you could post a new thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(ProjectDir)` is an MSBuild macro, if you want to use it in code then you'll need to transfer its value as preprocessor macro in project settings `MY_PROJECT_DIR="$(ProjectDir)"` and then change code to `readFile(MY_PROJECTS_DIR "shaders/vert.spv");`. You may also need to deal with escape sequences by using RAW string literal `MY_PROJECT_DIR=R"($(ProjectDir))"` for example, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. And the second part about RAW string literal, since I also faced that problem later.